# ¿Cómo abrir nueva ventana desde botón en control repeater Asp.Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

En mi WebForm Asp.Net tengo un control repeater, en la plantilla del repetear tengo un boton  lo que necesito  es cuando el cliente haga click en el boton Ejecute un método (Puede ser javascript o c#) que navegue a la URL que está en la propiedad CommandArgument de dicho boton (esta URL cambia con cada elemento) 
Mi Control Repeater

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptService" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate> 

                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("asin") %>' ></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title") %>' ></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("price") %>' ></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Image ID="imgItem" Width="150" Height="120" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("productImgUrl") %>' /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnShop"  runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShopNow") %>' Width="150" OnClick="GoProductUrl" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("productUrl") %>'  /> <br />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

la vista de la pagina 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: brother, llevas buen tiempo en el sitio, creo que deberías tener en cuenta que colocar código en texto ayuda más que un pantallazo del mismo. Aparte, decir "lo que necesito es cuando el cliente haga click en el boton Ejecute un método (Puede ser javascript o c#)" demuestra que: 1. Nada has intentado, 2. En WebForms: Ejecutar código JavaScript != Ejecutar código C#. Mejora la pregunta, intenta y te ayudamos a completar lo que tengas :D Saludos

Comment: si te da igual utilizar JS, puedes utilizar onclientclick en lugar de onclick y así poder ejecutar una función JS, pasarle como parámetro la URL y hacer con ella lo que quieras. Si necesitas hacerlo desde C# puedes llamar a un PageMethod o WebService una vez lo tengas en el JS.
No se si es esto lo que necesitas.
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Agrego un control HiddenFiel fuera del control repeater

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfUrlProduct" runat="server"  />
    <div style="background-color:gainsboro; padding:10px; margin:10px">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptService" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate> 

                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("asin") %>' ></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title") %>' ></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("price") %>' ></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Image ID="imgItem" Width="150" Height="120" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("productImgUrl") %>' /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnShop"  runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShopNow") %>' Width="150" OnClick="GoProductUrl" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("productUrl") %>'  /> <br />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

Agrego el metodo del boton q llama a una funcion javascript

```
   public void GoProductUrl(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Button k = (Button)sender;
           string url = k.CommandArgument;
           hdfUrlProduct.Value = url;
           String ScriptAct = "<script language='javascript'>" + "GoUrlProduct();"+ " </script>";
           ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GoUrlProduct();", ScriptAct);
        }
```

Mi funcion JavaScript

```
     <script language="javaScript" type="text/javaScript">

         function GoUrlProduct() {
             var urlProduct = <%=hdfUrlProduct.ClientID %>;
             window.open ( urlProduct.value);
         }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal con el boton hecho en html solo generando la url y el texto desde el servidor:

```
<input type="buttom" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShopNow") %>' onclick='window.open("<%# Eval("productUrl")  %>")'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba

```
PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("productUrl") %>'
```

y quitale el evento onclick

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Miguel. Por favor brinda más detalle sobre por qué estos cambios resolverían el problema. Indicar la causa también convendría. Considera que, actualmente, tu respuesta luce como un comentario. Conviene aplicar los cambios recomendados para que luzca como [una respuesta aceptable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/959/227)